# A good (open) place to let colleagues/peers review the material of one lecture?

Tags: meta

I am developing three lectures on [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). What is a good place to let peers and/or colleagues and/or students review the material online? Material includes: work sheets, exercises, quizzes, programming code (in R), and last but not least: the script and timeline for applying material.

Any platforms similar to code review stack exchange - see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/? Moreover: is mathematics educators *the* potential platform for such a review?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about Comp Sci course material review, not mathematical pedagogy

Comment: Math educators is not the potential platform for review since it is not a lecture on mathematics or math education.

Comment: While I personally consider the **concept** of dynamic programming the same as finding efficient recurrence relations, actual **code** in a real-world programming language is not mathematics, and this SE is definitely not a platform for reviews of lectures! You can ask specific questions about specific pedagogical technique, not ask for review... Especially if you're asking your colleagues and students to review the material! Instead, put it on your own blog.

Comment: @celeriko I agree that this question as stated is off-topic because of the content, but I think it is rooted in an interesting idea that could be converted into a suitable question. Consider something of the form: "I am developing a lecture on a mathematical topic that I will present to students. I am looking for an online venue where I can share the materials and solicit feedback from other math educators?" Although, now that I write it out, I suppose the answer would be this very site :-)

Comment: I voted to keep this question open because it is about mathematics education, on a topic that could also be called "recursive optimization".  See the Wikipedia article for examples and history, to avoid being blinded by a name which hid the subject's mathematical aspects.

Comment: @MattF. I see what you are saying and I agree that much, if not all, of computer science ultimately boils down to mathematics. However, unless I am gravely misunderstanding the OP, his question is specifically about a computer science/programming course/lecture.  Even if there is math in that course/lecture (which I am sure there is), this is not the correct venue for that question.  Furthermore, the question is about reviewing the OP's teaching materials which is also off-topic for this site.  There is a CS educators proposal in Area51 that seems like it has a good chance to make it to beta..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a review of lecture material being developed for a CS, rather than mathematics, curriculum.  While the two fields are related, this seems rather far afield from mathematics.